# when to use http & ftp when trying to access files from the server in C#

Tags: c#, file, http, ftp

anybody  please tell me when to use http & ftp when trying to access files from the server in C#

Comment: When you say the server can you elaborate on your scenario ?

Comment: HTTP is more responsive for request-response of small files, but FTP may be better for large files.

Comment: Is "the server" a HTTP or a FTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few considerations when making a decision between http and FTP. I would
Say it depends on who will be consuming your files and for what reason.

I would go http when

Hosting Html pages 
Hosting Json / XML data structures that are are representation of data from a database. Hosting Images
Generally when the user is a non technical web user that just needs to read your info.

I would use FTP

When the userbase is limited ( you are not allowing access with a web site)
If you need to allow read and write of large files.
FTP is a potential integration approach for passing information between two systems maybe even between 2 companies.